# Canonical or exemplary questions

Tags: discussion

I saw a question about Gaussian on reddit/comp_chem that contained a long input file without any `code` formatting. I wanted to find a good example of a Gaussian question on MMSE that exemplified how nice formatting would look, and to provide a link to that MMSE question for the user to see the benefits of having such nice-looking formatting. [This was the comment that I wrote in the end](https://www.reddit.com/r/comp_chem/comments/185ebgx/comment/kb1epkr/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), after going through our questions with the Gaussian tag, sorted by score, and finding one the first one that had a reasonably large `code block` for a Gaussin input file in it. I didn't look at any of the questions in this list after the one that I found and provided in my comment on Reddit, but a better example might exist.

This thread can contain "example" questions that we can easily provide others when we want to tell them something such as "this is how a great question looks". Hopefully we can find exemplary questions for [lammps](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lammps) and for [software-recommendations](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations) and for [software-input-file-request](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-input-file-request) and many other types of questions, so that whatever type of question is asked, we can direct users to good examples of similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

## Gaussian question example

**Gaussian question (with input file in code block)**:
This question: [What is Gaussian16's read-file logic when using ONIOM with genecp?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1368/5) was the one that I used [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/comp_chem/comments/185ebgx/comment/kb1epkr/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) when recommending someone to look at a decent example of a Gaussian question with an input file in a code block. After sorting questions with the [gaussian](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaussian) tag from highest to lowest score, this was the first one that had a large enough input file, by a user that still has a profile (this one: [How to fix Error Link9999 in Gaussian](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2080/5) has the same score and came first, but since I was showcasing an MMSE question to someone that might not have an MMSE account, I felt that one in which the OP still has a profile would look better). This question also has the same score and is also a good example: [CCSD and CISD size-consistency problem](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4693/5).